# Where can I find the File Type Verifier?

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests

As indicated here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I should be able to download the Windows 7 SDK.

This gets installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A

However this does not contain the File Type Verifier, unless I have missed it if they used a different name.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it at the following location: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\FileTypeVerifier.exe`

Comment: Those are a result of installing a /particular/ SDK.  Which one was it?

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for File Type Verifier when using Windows 10 SDK, it appears to be available at least for the 10.0.18362.0 version of the SDK, in folder `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0`, under both `x86` and `x64` folders (`arm` and `arm64`, too) there, as `filetypeverifier.exe`.

You may find it under a variation of the aforementioned path, due to a different version of the SDK, etc.